# How to change parameters to equations of physical properties they belong to in an equation?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, parametric-functions

First off, I want to apologize for my poor English as I am not a native speaker.

In my physics research, I had to solve a system of equations, from which I would get a solution for the speed of an object. I simplified the equations so instead of physical values (mass of air, mass of rocket etc.) there are parameters (a, b etc.)

Here is the system for anyone interested:

```
Solve[{ b y^2/2 + a x^2/2 + c z^2/2 == e, a x == b y + c z, (a + c)*q^2/2 + c z^2/2 == f, (a + c)*q == c z}, {x, y, z, q} ]
```

And the value I am searching for is `x`.

Obviously the solution is very long.

Here it is:

```
x=speed of missile=[(0.5*(-2.8284271247461903* a^2 c Sqrt[f (a+c)]-1* \[Sqrt](-8* a^5 b c f+21.74625462767236*a^5 b c-8* a^4 b^2 c f+21.74625462767236a^4 b^2 c-48* a^4 b c^2 f+130.47752776603417*a^4 b c^2-40*a^3 b^2 c^2 f+130.47752776603417*a^3 b^2 c^2-104*a^3 b c^3 f+260.95505553206834*a^3 b c^3-64*a^2 b^2 c^3 f+260.95505553206834*a^2 b^2 c^3-96*a^2 b c^4 f+173.9700370213789*a^2 b c^4-32*a b^2 c^4 f+173.9700370213789*a b^2 c^4-32* a b c^5 f)-5.656854249492381*a c^2 Sqrt[f (a+c)]))/(a^3 Sqrt[c (a+2* c)]+a^2 b Sqrt[c (a+2*c)]+2*a^2 c Sqrt[c (a+2*c)]+2*a b c Sqrt[c (a+2*c)])
```

And the solution is correct. But here a problem arises, all the parameters are 'connected' and can be expressed by two variables. Is there a clever way to exchange all the parameters for the equations of their physical quantities.

For example, if I know that:

```
b= (((100x* (1.5-y)* 28.97)/(8.31 * 288*1000))-((-0.5229242)(1/(288*(x/1)^((1-1.4)/1.4))))
```

and

```
c= y
```

and

```
d=((100x* (1.5-y)* 28.97)/(8.31 * 288*1000))
```

and so on

Is there a way to change all parameters in the solution to equations of their physical properties. By doing this I would get an equation which I can plot in 3d and then analyze.

I really hope I was clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The equations you showed are not compatible with *Mathematica* format. Could you show the actual *Mathematica* commands you used in solving this system of equations from which you obtained the expression for $x$ that you reported?

Comment: @MarcoB Yes of course. The command I used was :
solve:[((by^2)/2)+((ax^2)/2)+((cz^2)/2)=e , ax=by+cz , (((a+c)*q^2)/2)+((c*z^2)/2)=f ,((a+c)*q)=c*z ],{x,y,z, q}

Comment: Blaz, I'm confused. The code in your comment is not syntactically correct, nor does it work if I try to fix it as best I can. For example `=` is `Set`, the equal sign is `==`; `ax` is the name of a single variable, whereas `a x` is `a*x`, which I think is what you mean. That can't be the code you used! Have you tried pasting it it into *Mathematica* and running it?

Comment: @MarcoB Well yes, when you asked for the code I just copied it from the mathematica window. I'm confused as well, how come if the code is wrong Mathematica still interpreted it correctly?

Yeah when I wrote ax I actually meant a*x. As x,y,z,q are the variables and a,b,c,d,e,f are the parameters

Comment: Blaz, I'm not sure what to say, but the code in your comment simply can't run as is. The following works to produce a solution: 
`Solve[{
  b y^2/2 + a x^2/2 + c z^2/2 == e,
  a x == b y + c z,
  (a + c)*q^2/2 + c z^2/2 == f,
  (a + c)*q == c z},
 {x, y, z, q}
 ]`

However, I don't know how you obtained results including approximate numbers in your posted solution for $x$, since all numbers are expressed in arbitrary precision. I suspect that something is still unclear here. I would strongly suggest that you edit your question to show complete and correct code to start.

Comment: @MarcoB Sure, will do. Maybe the way I am asking the question is weird. Is there a place for beginners to learn how to use Mathematica properly. Maybe If I read through it I could help myself.

Comment: I just want to comment that your "poor English" is better than far too many native speakers/writers...

Comment: Blaz, let me point you to these two questions on this site that are a wonderful collection of resources for beginners and experience users alike: [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/27951), and [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/27951). Both have a "basic" section with quite a few interesting pointers etc. The second question also has a lot of pointers to tutorials and learning guides that you might find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the function `With`. From the documentation:

```
With[{x=x0, y=y0, ...}, expr}
```

specifies that in *expr* all occurrences of x, y, ... should be replace by x0, y0, ...

In your example you would write something like:

```
With[
  {
   b = ((100 x*(1.5 - y)*28.97)/(8.31*288*1000)) - ...,
   c = y,
   d = ((100 x*(1.5 - y)*28.97)/(8.31*288*1000)),
   ...
   },

  (0.5*(-2.8284271247461903*a^2 c Sqrt[f (a + c)] - ...)
   ]
```

Comment: Or a replacement rule.  `(final expression)/.{x->x0,y->y0,z->z0,...}`